# align decimal point vim

Tags: regex, vim

I have a column of data which looks like this:

```
0.934 
-0.3423
2.346621
0.0032
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
 0.934 
-0.3423
 2.346621
 0.0032
```

Is there a regex in VIM to do that or a plugin?

thanks.

Comment: Is there always just one digit before the `.`?

Comment: in principle not, there could be more digits

Answer (score 2):

In `linux` you can do this:

```
:%!tr . ' ' | xargs printf '\%10s.\%-10s\n'
```

#### output:

```
     0.934
    -0.3423
     2.346621
     0.0032
```

There is a `printf()` function in `vim`. So you can play this trick in vim:

```
:%s/\v(.*)\.(.*)/\=printf('%10s.%-10s', submatch(1), submatch(2))
```

Comment: thanks, it works. How could I align that column if it is just one column in a file containing several columns. Let say that column is in the middle of columns 1 and 3?

Comment: Try `\%V` to Match inside the Visual area.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [align plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294).

Comment: how could I do that?  I selected the text with Crtl+v and then applied " align \. " to align by the decimal point, I aligned the decimal point but the digits become separated from the decimal point.

Comment: Excellent @Spencer Rathbun ! For me it worked in the following way: :AlignCtrl =rp0P0l

Comment: @armando alright, I ran a test and my comment didn't seem correct. Glad to know it worked out.